# How to Dockerize CodeEffects Rules Engine Angular Implementation

Tags: rule-engine, business-rules, codeeffects

We are using [CodeEffects Rules Engine with Angular Implementation](https://codeeffects.com/Doc/Business-Rule-Implementation-Example-Core-Angular) and trying to dockerize the application. But the build is throwing an exception; need help from this group in resolving the error.

Below is my docker script and also attaching the error screenshot for reference

**NOTE:** Application works fine without docker in local.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env

RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y wget && \
apt-get install -y gnupg2 && \
wget -qO- https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash - && \
apt-get install -y build-essential nodejs

WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "CodeEffects.Rule.Angular.Demo.dll"]
```

Comment: Dockerizing has nothing to do with Code Effects. It's possible that the demo project you use has something that doesn't work with Docker. Try creating your own empty Angular web app from scratch, adding Code Effects editor, and dockerizing that one instead.

Comment: @Alex - Thank you, am trying the same, could you please help which dll file I should use in my docker file just to run dot net app? Currently am using "CodeEffects.Rule.Angular.Demo.dll" which is trying to build angular as well. Am very new to this, any help here would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Angular has nothing to do with .NET platform you are trying to use. The type of the CodeEffects dll files you need to use depends on the .NET web platform your project is based on. All Code Effects assemblies are available on NuGet, the editor is free to use. Please consult the following article for details: https://codeeffects.com/Doc/Business-Rule-Implementation